# Solving circuits using kirchhoff's laws and elimination method ( not any matrix method)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

I need to solve this problem as part of my review in college physics. The task is to find the value of 5 branch currents using  Kirchhoff's laws and elimination method (or maybe called elimination by substitution BUT not using any matrix method).

The circuit is:
[image]

I got the KCL equations:

a: $I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0$

b: $I_3- I_4- I_5 = 0$

and the KVL equations:

$\text{Loop 1}: 15 - 4I_1 - 6I_2 = 0$

$\text{Loop 2}: 6I_2 - I_3- 3I_4 = 0$

$\text{Loop 3}: 3I_4 - 2I_5 - 10 =0$

My problem is I can't get the correct answer by elimination method. Please help me to provide the solution if the given answers are:

> $I_1 = 1.89$
>   $I_2 = 1.24$
>   $I_3 = 0.65$
>   $I_4 = 2.26$
>   $I_5 = -1.61$

Please show the solution and give tips on how to solve this type of problems using elimination method so other students can benefit and learn here.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me that you setup the loop equations correctly. I substituted your KCL equations for $i_2$ and $i_4$ into the loop equations so that there was only $i_1$, $i_3$ and $i_5$ to solve for, and I was able to get the correct answers that you gave.

[image]

I also checked these answers with a PSpice simulation, and they agree with your answers as well as the matrix solutions above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We got $5$ linear equations and $5$ variables. There are many ways to solve it but i'll use [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) as you asked. It's all about mathematics.

> Tip: Use  [Cramer's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule), it is the easiest.

$1i_1+(−1i_2)+(−1i_3)+(0i_4)+(0i_5)=0 \tag{1}$
  $0i_1+(0i_2)+(1i_3)+(-1i_4)+(-1i_5)=0 \tag{2}$
  $-4i_1+(−6i_2)+(0i_3)+(0i_4)+(0i_5)=-15 \tag{3}$
  $0i_1+(−6i_2)+(−1i_3)+(-3i_4)+(0i_5)=0 \tag{4}$
  $0i_1+(01i_2)+(0i_3)+(3i_4)+(-2i_5)=0 \tag{5}$

In matrix form taking the respective coofficients
 [image: image 0]

> Tip:The best way to solve by elimination is convert the matrix into an upper triangular matrix or in echolon form.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]
Which is the correct solution.

> Last tip: Do the rough work at some other page and write each reduced matrix on another plain page.